# Trying to insert a random six digit code/number in mysql table but it is giving same for every new registered users

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert 6 digits number in mysql table through php but every time I tried to register a new user, it is giving the same sequence of code.
I have done something like this

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['generate']))
{

$num = (rand(111111, 999999));

file_get_contents("mylink");

$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET otp='".$num."'");
$qry_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

header("location: otp.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: so you want to update all user data with 6 digits random number?

Comment: it means every time same 6 digit insert to database ?

Comment: Yes @Naushil and then will use that number to validate users in the next screen so that they can avail some option.

Comment: Exactly @TarangP. If I register a new user, the number is inserted but the same number is updated for another users as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You Are not Put Any Condition in Your Query.
So now it will update all users and set same random number to all fields.
Build Query Like this

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET otp='".$num."' WHERE USERID = 1 ");
```

Comment: Thanks Tarang.. got it.. One more query is that how to make it dynamic like I have column name clientid.
so I am trying WHERE clientid = ':clientid', but it is not giving the result.

Comment: your welcome @A.Alam.if you find answer you can mark this as answer.

Comment: You didn't tell me how to make it dynamic, so that I need not to change that id every time.

Comment: @A.Alam The person answered your original question and it should be marked as the solution given for it. What you're asking here is another question, so you will need to close the present question and open a new one; that's how things work here on Stack.